# How to choose the most common value in a group related to other group in R?

Tags: r, sorting, group-by

I have in R the following data frame:

```
ID = c(rep(1,5),rep(2,3),rep(3,2),rep(4,6));ID
VAR = c("A","A","A","A","B","C","C","D",
             "E","E","F","A","B","F","C","F");VAR
CATEGORY = c("ANE","ANE","ANA","ANB","ANE","BOO","BOA","BOO",
        "CAT","CAT","DOG","ANE","ANE","DOG","FUT","DOG");CATEGORY

DATA = data.frame(ID,VAR,CATEGORY);DATA
```

That looks like this table below :

| ID | VAR | CATEGORY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | ANE |
| 1 | A | ANE |
| 1 | A | ANA |
| 1 | A | ANB |
| 1 | B | ANE |
| 2 | C | BOO |
| 2 | C | BOA |
| 2 | D | BOO |
| 3 | E | CAT |
| 3 | E | CAT |
| 4 | F | DOG |
| 4 | A | ANE |
| 4 | B | ANE |
| 4 | F | DOG |
| 4 | C | FUT |
| 4 | F | DOG |

ideal output given the above data frame in R I want to be like that:

| ID | TEXTS | category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | ANE |
| 2 | C | BOO |
| 3 | E | CAT |
| 4 | F | DOG |

More specifically: I want for ID say 1 to search the most common value in the column VAR which is A and then to search the most common value in the column CATEGORY related to the most common value A which is the ANE and so forth.

How can I do it in R ?
Imagine that it is sample example.My real data frame contains 850.000 rows and has 14000 unique ID.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another `dplyr` strategy using `count` and `slice`:

```
library(dplyr)
DATA %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    count(VAR, CATEGORY) %>% 
    slice(which.max(n)) %>% 
    select(-n)
```

```
     ID VAR   CATEGORY
  <dbl> <chr> <chr>   
1     1 A     ANE     
2     2 C     BOA     
3     3 E     CAT     
4     4 F     DOG
```

Answer (score 3):

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
DATA %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(VAR == names(sort(table(VAR), decreasing=TRUE))[1]) %>%
  group_by(ID, VAR) %>%
  summarize(CATEGORY = names(sort(table(CATEGORY), decreasing=TRUE))[1]) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 4 x 3
#      ID VAR   CATEGORY
#   <dbl> <chr> <chr>   
# 1     1 A     ANE     
# 2     2 C     BOA     
# 3     3 E     CAT     
# 4     4 F     DOG
```

---

Data

```r
DATA <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4), VAR = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "C", "C", "D", "E", "E", "F", "A", "B", "F", "C", "F"), CATEGORY = c("ANE", "ANE", "ANA", "ANB", "ANE", "BOO", "BOA", "BOO", "CAT", "CAT", "DOG", "ANE", "ANE", "DOG", "FUT", "DOG")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))
```

Answer (score 2):

We could modify the [`Mode`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31400445/r-how-to-find-the-mode-of-a-vector) to return the index and use that in `slice` after grouping by 'ID'

```
Modeind <- function(x) {
   ux <- unique(x)
   which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))
   }
library(dplyr)
DATA %>%
     group_by(ID) %>%
     slice(Modeind(VAR)) %>%
     ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
     ID VAR   CATEGORY
  <dbl> <chr> <chr>   
1     1 A     ANE     
2     2 C     BOO     
3     3 E     CAT     
4     4 F     DOG
```

Comment: .@akrun, yours is the only one, which reflects OPs ouptput. In ID 2 which one should be choosen `BOA` or `BOO`. Both are possible?

Comment: @TarJae In the `Modeind` function it is jus selecting the first occurrence in case of ties.  I don't know whether they need to sample in that case or not

Comment: @TarJae I noticed that. In those cases when there is not a clear order (other than as-presented), I tend to infer ties don't matter much. If the OP needs something else, they'll say it or it will come out in spiral-development.

Answer (score 2):

A base R option with nested `subset` + `ave`

```
subset(
  subset(
    DATA,
    !!ave(ave(ID, ID, VAR, FUN = length), ID, FUN = function(x) x == max(x))
  ),
  !!ave(ave(ID, ID, VAR, CATEGORY, FUN = length), ID, VAR, FUN = function(x) seq_along(x) == which.max(x))
)
```

gives

```
   ID VAR CATEGORY
1   1   A      ANE
6   2   C      BOO
9   3   E      CAT
11  4   F      DOG
```

---

## Explanation

1. The inner `subset` + `ave` is to filter out the rows with the most common `VAR` values (grouped by `ID`)
2. Based on the trimmed data frame the previous step, the outer `subset` + `ave` is to filter out the rows with the most common `CATEGORY` values ( grouped by `ID` + `VAR`)

Comment: Could you please explain with your words the logic. Is just for me to better memorize. Thank you.

Comment: @TarJae Yes, now the explanations are added.