# Replace value in column with two variables by the most frequent value in matrix in R

Tags: r

I have following matrix.

```
r1 <- c("M","A","T","D","T","Y")
r2 <- c("M","A","G","G","D", "J")
r3 <- c("M","B","H","G","T", "Y")
r4 <- c("M","B","G","G","X", "Y")
r5<- c("F","A","H","D","T", "Y")
n.mat <- rbind(r1,r2,r3,r4,r5)
n.mat<-as.data.frame(n.mat)
```

I would like to replace values in columns with only two values by the most frequent value (for each column). And leave columns with more than two unique values as they are.

Output:

```
r1 <- c("M","A","T","G","T","Y")
r2 <- c("M","A","G","G","D", "Y")
r3 <- c("M","A","H","G","T", "Y")
r4 <- c("M","A","G","G","X", "Y")
r5<- c("M","A","H","G","T", "Y")
n.mat <- rbind(r1,r2,r3,r4,r5)
n.mat<-as.data.frame(n.mat)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may use the [`Mode`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31400445/r-how-to-find-the-mode-of-a-vector) function with a condition check on the `length` of `unique` elements in the column i.e. `if` the number of `unique` elements is greater than 2, return the column or else get the `Mode`

```
n.mat[] <- lapply(n.mat, function(x) if(length(unique(x)) > 2) x else Mode(x))
```

where

```
Mode <- function(x) {
  ux <- unique(x)
  ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}
```

-output

```
> n.mat
   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
r1  M  A  T  G  T  Y
r2  M  A  G  G  D  Y
r3  M  A  H  G  T  Y
r4  M  A  G  G  X  Y
r5  M  A  H  G  T  Y
```

---

If we need a `matrix` as output, use `as.matrix` on the output above

```
n.mat <- as.matrix(n.mat)
```

---

Or use `apply` instead of `lapply`

```
apply(n.mat, 2, FUN = function(x) if(length(unique(x)) > 2) x 
       else rep(Mode(x), length(x)))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this looks perfect, but in the end I don't get a matrix, don't I?

Comment: @Luker354 you start with a data.frame.  So, it ends up with the same structure.  If you need a matrix, just do `n.mat <- as.matrix(n.mat)`