# Creating new variables with links between cases via id's (longitudinal data)

Tags: r, dplyr, longitudinal

I have a dataframe with two persons in three points of time (3x "id" == 1 and 3x "id" == 2):

```
id <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2)
id2 <- c(NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1)
x <- c(4, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1)
dat1 <- data.frame(id, id2, x)
dat1

  id id2 x
1  1  NA 4
2  1  NA 5
3  1  NA 5
4  2   1 1
5  2   1 1
6  2   1 1
```

Now i want to create a new variable "y" with following rule: If "id2" is not NA, "y" should be the value of "x" that occurs most often for the person with "id2" == "id". In this example data: For all points in time, the person with "id" == 2 gets a 5 in "y", because person 2 has a 1 in "id2" and 5 is the number that occurs most often for the person with "id" == 1. Since "id2" is NA for person 1, "y" will be NA aswell (there is no other person to refer to for person 1). Result is:

```
  id id2 x y
1  1  NA 4 NA
2  1  NA 5 NA
3  1  NA 5 NA
4  2   1 1 5
5  2   1 1 5
6  2   1 1 5
```

Is there a way to do this with dplyr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may find the [`Mode`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31400445/r-how-to-find-the-mode-of-a-vector) grouped by 'id', then `match` the 'id2' with 'id' and replace with the 'Mode' values

```
library(dplyr)
dat1 %>% 
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(tmp = Mode(x)) %>% 
    ungroup %>%
    mutate(y= tmp[match(id2, id)], tmp = NULL)
```

where

```
Mode <- function(x) {
  ux <- unique(x)
  ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}
```

Comment: A follow-up question: How do i set the value for "y" always to the same value as "x" for the matched person? That means in this example data: Person with "id" = 1, which is matched with person 2 via "id2", gets y: c(4, 5, 5) (since there is no "id2" or match for person with "id" = 2, y will still be NA for person 2). This rule is less complex and could be useful in further work...

Comment: @C.F.  Maybe you need `match(id2, unique(id))` ?  Can you please post as a new question to underestand it better. thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70017603/new-variables-using-ids-linking-different-cases-in-longidutinal-data