# Return most common value in column by group, replace null in that column with that value

Tags: r, dplyr

I'd like to replace the na values in my df column with the most common value by group

```
#Ex:

df <- data.frame(Home_Abbr = c('PHI', 'PHI', 'DAL', 'PHI'),
                 Home_City = c('Philadelphia', 'Philadelphia', 'Dallas', NULL))

#Desired Result

Home_Abbr   Home_City

PHI         Philadelphia
PHI         Philadelphia
DAL         Dallas
PHI         Philadelphia
```

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
df <- df %>%
  group_by(Home_Abbr) %>%
  mutate(Home_City = names(which.max(table(Home_City))))
```

But when I run this I get a 'Can't combine NULL and non NULL results' Error.

Comment: `NA` is missing value and not `NULL`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use [`Mode`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31400445/r-how-to-find-the-mode-of-a-vector) function

```
 Mode <- function(x) {
  ux <- unique(x)
  ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}
```

and then `replace`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(Home_Abbr) %>%
  mutate(Home_City = replace(Home_City, is.na(Home_City), 
      Mode(Home_City))) %>%
  ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 2
  Home_Abbr Home_City   
  <chr>     <chr>       
1 PHI       Philadelphia
2 PHI       Philadelphia
3 DAL       Dallas      
4 PHI       Philadelphia
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Home_Abbr = c("PHI", "PHI", "DAL", "PHI"), Home_City = c("Philadelphia", 
"Philadelphia", "Dallas", NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```