# Assign most common value of factor variable with summarize in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, summarize

R noob here, working in `tidyverse` / RStudio.

I have a categorical / factor variable that I'd like to retain in a `group_by`/`summarize` workflow. I'd like to `summarize` it using a summary function that returns the most common value of that factor within each group.

Is there a summary function I can use for this?

`mean` returns `NA`, `median` only works with numeric data, and `summary` gives me separate rows with counts of each factor level instead of the most common level.

Edit: example using subset of `mtcars` dataset:

```
mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear carb 
<dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <fct>
21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4 4    
21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4 4    
22.8     4  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4 1    
21.4     6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3 1    
18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3 2    
18.1     6  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3 1    
14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3 4    
24.4     4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4 2    
22.8     4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4 2    
19.2     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4 4
```

Here I have converted `carb` into a factor variable. In this subset of the data, you can see that among 6-cylinder cars there are 3 with `carb=4` and 1 with `carb=1`; similarly among 4-cylinder cars there are 2 with `carb=2` and 1 with `carb=1`.

So if I do:

```
data %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise(modalcarb = FUNC(carb))
```

where `FUNC` is the function I'm looking for, I should get:

```
cyl carb 
<dbl> <fct>
4    2    
6    4    
8    2  # there are multiple potential ways of handling multi-modal situations, but that's secondary here
```

Hope that makes sense!

Comment: You can use [Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31400445/r-how-to-find-the-mode-of-a-vector) i.e `df1 %>% group_by(yourgroup) %>% summarise(Mode = Mode(yourcolumn))`

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example with the expected output?

Comment: @akrun is there a built-in function that does that?

Comment: Not sure if there are any packages that have this function or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the function `fmode` of `collapse` to calculate the mode. Here I created a reproducible example using `mtcars` dataset where the `cyl` column is your factor variable to group on like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(collapse)

mtcars %>%
  mutate(cyl = as.factor(cyl)) %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarise(mode = fmode(am))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   cyl    mode
#>   <fct> <dbl>
#> 1 4         1
#> 2 6         0
#> 3 8         0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

We could use `which.max` after `count`:

```
library(dplyr)

# fake dataset
x <- mtcars %>% 
  mutate(cyl = factor(cyl)) %>% 
  select(cyl) 

x %>% 
  count(cyl) %>% 
  slice(which.max(n))
```

```
  cyl       n
  <fct> <int>
1 8        14
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `which.max` to index and `table` to count.

```r
library(tidyverse)

mtcars |>
  group_by(cyl) |>
  summarise(modalcarb = carb[which.max(table(carb))])
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>     cyl modalcarb
#>   <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1     4         2
#> 2     6         4
#> 3     8         3
```